# Find integer values that when multiplied together equal a given value

Tags: integers

Given a = bc, with a known integer a, is it possible to find all b and c values that are integers quickly without testing each b and c value?

As an example a = 194920496263521028482429080527, is it possible to quickly find integer values for b and c?

Comment: In general it is not easy to find all such $b$ and $c$ (basically this is factorization problem). However once we know the prime factorization of $a$, then yes.

Comment: Ok thanks, but is there a quicker way than individually testing all integer values of b and c?

Comment: You need to find the prime factors

Comment: [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Comment: For your example, here's [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+194920496263521028482429080527).  I hope you were not expecting to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).  From the factorization of an integer, it is mechanical to write every possible pair of two integers whose product is the given integer.

The method you mention in comments, "a quicker way than individually testing all integer values of $b$ and $c$" is similar to, but less efficient than trial division, trying each integer in $[1,\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor ]$ as a candidate for $b$ and determining whether each choice of $b$ makes $a/b$ an integer or not.

There are *much* faster methods than trial division.  There is not a method that one would consider "fast" for integers of unlimited size.

For your particular example, 
$$  194920496263521028482429080527  \\
= 289673451203483 \cdot 672897345109469  $$ 
is the only product giving that number that does not have $b=1$ or $c = 1$.